# Working with <- in Swift

Tags: swift, objectmapper

I was looking at [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) libary. And noticed the `<-` operator.

How does this exactly work ?

```
// Mappable
func mapping(map: Map) {
    username    <- map["username"]
    age         <- map["age"]
    weight      <- map["weight"]
    array       <- map["arr"]
    dictionary  <- map["dict"]
    bestFriend  <- map["best_friend"]
    friends     <- map["friends"]
    birthday    <- (map["birthday"], DateTransform())
}
```

Also how does the following line work

```
birthday    <- (map["birthday"], DateTransform())
```

I understand that `birthday` is now a tuple. Which can be access by

```
self.birthday.0
self.birthday.1
```

Although the property is defined like so

```
var birthday: NSDate?
```

How does a tuple respond as a `NSDate` (in this case) ?

Thanks!

Comment: That's probably the users custom overloaded operator. You'll have to look at his assignment to understand its functionality

Comment: Read up on **Custom Transforms** on that Github page you linked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you [look at his Operators.Swift](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper/blob/master/ObjectMapper/Core/Operators.swift) file in his core library you'll find all of the overloads for his custom operator.

He defines his custom operator:

```
infix operator <- {}
```

Then he has quite a few overloads for his operator, here's the first overload from his list:

```
/// Object of Basic type
public func <- <T>(inout left: T, right: Map) {
    switch right.mappingType {
    case .FromJSON:
        FromJSON.basicType(&left, object: right.value())
    case .ToJSON:
        ToJSON.basicType(left, map: right)
    }
}
```

You'll need to go through each of his overloads to understand how they function, and he has *dozens* of them.

### [Operators](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper/blob/master/ObjectMapper/Core/Operators.swift)

Comment: Ah right! Thanks a lot. It had me puzzled for a couple of days now.

Comment: @PrakashRaman Understandable... Operator overloading is such a great feature in Swift.